# Textbox doesn't refresh and is in break mode after a little time

Tags: c#, wpf, loops, crash

I am making a simple wpf application. It has a button and a textbox and when you click the button it should update the textbox the whole time(see code). I have 3 problems:

1. It doesn't update the textbox in the loop.
2. When I click the button It is stuck and I can't close the application(only with taskmanager and stop debugging).
3. If i leave the textbox stuck and do not close it. After a minute or so I get this error: ContextSwitchDeadlock occurred with the break mode screen.

I have tried to solve the problem by searching on the internet but I didn't succeed. I hope you guys are able to solve it:). And the code is here:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = RandomNumber();
    }

    private string TextboxData;
    private int RandomNumber()
    {
        int x = 0;
        int i = 0;
        Random rng = new Random();
        do
        {
            x = rng.Next(1, 1000000);
            i++;
            TextboxData += "\r\nAl zo vaak :O" + i; //the rng loop
            textBox.Text = TextboxData;                
        }
        while (x != 1);
        TextboxData += "\r\nHij heeft zo vaak geprobeerd 1 te halen " + i;
        textBox.Text = TextboxData + Environment.NewLine;
        return x;
    }       
}
```

Comment: What is TextboxData, just a string?

Comment: @KevinKal it's declared before  `RandomNumber` method: `private string TextboxData;`

Comment: Ohlol, I'm stupid. Anyway, there is a really low chance x becomes 1. So your program basically spams the chatbox pretty fast. 
Why don't you just `textBox.AppendText` ?

Comment: I made this program for a friend that is always with his calculator trying to get 1 with a chance for 1 to a million :P. It worked with console application but I wanted an interface

Comment: one advice - Always use stringBuilder when it comes to huge concatenation !!!!!

Comment: @Nikita that wouldn't really work out. He wants an immediate output, using StringBuilder won't help at all.

Wouter, tried adding a little Thread.Sleep ?
And get rid of the TextboxData and use textBox.AppendText

Man man man :)

Comment: you can also supress ContextSwitchDeadlock by adding [MTAThreadAttribute] applied to the Main() method.

Comment: @KevinKal Yes, that can be one way to go around since Textboxdata is more like a backUp variable.

Comment: It's a bit pointless if you ask me, haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all your actions are made in main GUI thread.
That means that your program can't redraw interface because it's busy executing code in loop.

In order to achieve desired results you need to execute your loop asynchronous. But we must keep in mind that GUI should be updated only from GUI thread( it's framework requirement).

Due to quick calculations the texbox will be updated too often. You may consider using `Thread.Sleep(100)`.

Here's solution:

```
    private async void Play_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = await RandomNumber();
    }

    private async Task<int> RandomNumber()
        {
            int x = 0;
            int i = 0;
            string text = string.Empty;
            Random rng = new Random();

            // This will start work in background. Leaving GUI thread to it's own tasks.
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                do
                {
                    x = rng.Next(1, 1000000);
                    i++;
                    text = "\r\nAl zo vaak :O" + i.ToString(); //the rng loop

                    // This will invoke textbox update in GUI thread satisfying update requirement.
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,
                        new Action(() => {  textBox.AppendText(text); }));

                    // We will make it slower in order to see updates at adequate rate.
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                while (x != 1);    
            }); 

            // thanks to await we will have this code executed after we found our x==1.
            text = "\r\nHij heeft zo vaak geprobeerd 1 te halen " + i;

            textBox.AppendText(text);
            return x;
        }
```

Don't forget to add following usings:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Threading;
```

**EDIT**: I don't know why you want to have return value from RandomNumber() (it will always be 1. so it's pontless). But to handle that correctly we need to add `async` to our signatures in order to use `await` so we could get a value, execute code after awaited block and return result.

It's a pretty complicated topic, which I will only mention here in order to have correct solution. If you're interested - google '.net async await'. But I suggest to leave it for future :)

Also, I removed `TextBoxData` field and replaced it with local variable and used `textbox.AppendText()` as @KevinKal suggested.

Comment: I will try this immediately when I am out of school(around 15.30)

Comment: If I make the method void do I still need to add that async thing?

Comment: The only thing that `async` do is enable usage of `await`. If you want void method with `async`, then you should declare it return type as `Task`. In serious projects it's not recommended to have `async Task` methods. They're allowed only for event handlers(such as `Play_Click`). But in your case I don't think that you should care now :) So you can just declare your `RandomNumber` as `private async Task RandomNumber()`. You need here `async`, because without `await` your last appendage to textbox won't work properly.

Comment: I will have a look now

Comment: got an error that says it returns the wrong type here is the exact discription: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0407 'Task MainWindow.Play_Click(object, RoutedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type MaxenJorisfrustratie(met gui)again C:\Documenten\wouter\Csharp\C# visual studio apps\MaxenJorisfrustratie(met gui)again\MaxenJorisfrustratie(met gui)again\obj\Debug\MainWindow.g.i.cs\..\..\MainWindow.xaml 11

Comment: Oh, well , my bad. For event handlers you should use `async void` not `async Task`. I will update answer right now.

Comment: Can I ask you one more thing?? I would love it if it you would see the latest line that is added because I have to scroll the whole time atm

Comment: May I add you on skype or teamspeak(I pref skype tbh)?

Comment: Nvm I didn't fix it. @CodingFeles I really want to show you the bug :). If you have time pls add me on skype( username: wouterrobot).

Comment: I'm sorry. It's not possible. Please, try to find solution or post another question and describe your problem and attempts to solve it. Maybe it was already asked on SO.